# Which types of permissions among recently separated 4 types account permissions of 1. Manage Users, 2. Edit, 3. Collaborate, 4. Read & Analyze are req

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, connector, gooddata

Which types of permissions among recently separated 4 types account permissions of 1. Manage Users, 2. Edit, 3. Collaborate, 4. Read & Analyze are required for Google Analytics User Account which is to be applied for GoodData CloudConnect Google Analytics reader ETL component?

Types of permissions to be applied to a Google Analytics user account have been recently separated and increased into 4, that are; 
1. Manage Users, 2. Edit, 3. Collaborate, 4. Read & Analyze

What I would like to know is which of above permissions will be at least required for a GA account to successfully retrieve GA data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that 4. Read & Analyze was the only necessary type of permission for GA account to retrieve analysis data from GA.